# Need assistance setting UIButton in centre using Autolayouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to programmatically set the `UIButton` vertically and horizontally in centre using `AutoLayouts` here is my code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
UIView *av = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 35.0)];

UIButton *doneButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 30)];

//UIButton title, color, backgroung color, targer action ...

NSLayoutConstraint* cn3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneButton
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:av
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0];
    [av addConstraint:cn3];

    NSLayoutConstraint* cn4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneButton
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:av
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:0];
    [av addConstraint:cn4];

[av addSubview:doneButton];
    self.theTextField.inputAccessoryView = av;
}
```

The above code is working fine except one thing, I am getting this warning in console:

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:
>   NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcfc494efb0
>   UIButton:0x7fcfc2624420'Done'.centerX ==
>   UIView:0x7fcfc2624230.centerX
>
> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of
>   that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint
>   needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on
>   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.

And getting same warning for Y.

Please tell me what is going wrong why I am getting this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `doneButton` to the `av` view **before** setting your constraints.

```
[av addSubview:doneButton];

[av addConstraint:cn3];
[av addConstraint:cn4];
```